# Navigate between windows in WinUI 3

Tags: c#, windows, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I am building a program where the main window (MainWindow) has a "Login" button. Login button takes you to LoginWindow. How do I navigate from the MainWindow to the LoginWindow on the click of a button? Or maybe activate the login window and deactivate main window? I am very new to WinUI and Windows App SDK. Thanks!
[Main window and the login button function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzGhr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ContentDialog` and put your LoginPage in it.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<StackPanel x:Name="Root">
    <Button
        Click="LoginButton_Click"
        Content="Login" />
</StackPanel>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
private async void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContentDialog dialog = new();
    dialog.XamlRoot = Root.XamlRoot;
    dialog.Title = "Login";
    dialog.CloseButtonText = "Cancel";
    dialog.Content = new LoginPage();
    ContentDialogResult result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

**LoginPage.xaml**

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Username" />
    <TextBox />
    <TextBlock Text="Password" />
    <PasswordBox />
</StackPanel>
```